# UICollectionViewCell strange behaviour. Cells not updating layer correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

I have a `UICollectionView` with multiple cells on which I add a `CAGradient` layer representing the color of each cell. The problem is that when I push another view controller on top of the present view controller and then pop the second view controller, my collection view cells shift colors in a random order. To give you an idea I have attached screenshots.

This is the original order of the cells. This is correct
[image: This is the original order of the cells. This is correct]

This happens when I push another view controller and then return
[image: This happens when I push another view controller and then return]
You can see that the cells shifted their colors even though I changed nothing.

This is the code I use to initialize the cells.

[collectionview reloadData] is called in -viewWillAppear so the cells load every time the view appears

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self filterRecords];
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProspectCVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    for (int i = 0; i < [eventsSortedForAddedDate count]; i++)
    {
        Events* event = (Events*)[eventsSortedForAddedDate objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([event.activityLevel.activityName isEqualToString:@"None"])
            continue;

        color = [[event activityLevel] color];

        if (![color isEqualToString:@"#FFCCCCCC"])
            break;
        else
            color = nil;
    }


    if (!([color length] > 0) || color == nil)
    {
        color = @"#FFCCCCCC";
    }

    UIColor* myColor = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:color alpha:.9];

    //cell.backgroundColor = myColor;

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[myColor CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.85f],  nil];
    //[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];


    cell.prospectImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.prospectImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3.0);
    cell.prospectImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
    cell.prospectImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;

    cell.cellLabel.text = p.displayName;

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

There is nothing wrong in the way I get the color, I have debugged multiple times and checked that the colors I get are the correct ones.
If I do

```
cell.backgroundColor = myColor;
```

The cells do not change their colors and function as expected. So I am pretty sure that the problem lies with the CAGradientLayer.

I have tried everything that I could think of but nothing seems to work!

Comment: If  `[event.activityLevel.activityName isEqualToString:@"None"]`  then you `continue` but what happen if you not get `none` throughout the loop?

Comment: Then the if condition below it gets executed, as the color would be nil and I will assign the default color which is a shade of gray. But as you can see from the screenshots above that is not the case. I am getting the color values correctly. Like I mentioned, if I do cell.backgroundColor = myColor, the cells function as intended. The problem occurs when I use CAGradientLayer

Comment: try my answer, it may work!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once,

```
 [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:[[cell.layer sublayers] indexOfObject:[[cell.layer sublayers] lastObject]]];
```

instead of

```
 [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

**Update :**

As asked in comment, [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:) states about `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`,

> Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

**`And second thing you can also remove previous layers and then can add new one at index 0. it is better because it not increase number of layer which is not necessary.`**

Comment: Thank you!! That's why they call you the Lion :D It had me scratching my head for the last 8 hours. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Though I still do not understand what caused the problem in the first place. The cells are being created every time I reload right? Then why are the layers not being created also. Or are the cells being dequed? I still am a little confused over the concept of dequeing

Comment: Thank you, that is a big help. Although I did try to remove the layers before adding the gradient layer but it just crashed the app. I may not have removed them correctly. I did this [[cell.layer sublayers] removeObjectAtIndex:0]

Comment: first you should check in if statement that layer is there then you should remove. `[cell.layer sublayers] ` returns NSArray so you can't remove object from it as it is not mutable. so you should use `[layer removeFromSuperlayer];`